# How to use JOptionPane with many options? java

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I was experimenting with different `JOptionPane` and I came across having different options in a array and then using it on `JOptionPane`. However I am finding it hard to use the given options, so for example, how would I use my GO back option?

```
  String[] options = new String[] {"Go ahead", "Go back", "Go forward", "close me"};
      int option =  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Title", "Message", 
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
            null, options, options[0]);
```

I have tried doing it like this but it won't work

```
    if (option == JOptionPane.options[1]){

    }
```

edit:

```
 switch(option){
          case 1: System.out.println("1");
              break;
          case 2: System.out.println("2");
              break;
          case 3: System.out.println("3");
              break;
          case 4: System.out.println("4");
              break;
          }
```

Comment: You get a int from the Optionpane. You should say if(option == 1){.

Comment: would it be possible, say for example if the text on one of the button is long e.g. "Open window 2 and close window 1" then would it it possible to split them to two lines e.g. open window 2 on the first line and close window 1 on the second line.

Comment: Try HTML "<html><body> Open window 2 <br /> and close window 1 </body></html>"

Comment: @pL4Gu33, its not working.

Comment: sure? In my example it works perfect. Your array should looks like: String[] options = new String[] {"<html><body> Open window 2 <br /> and close window 1 </body></html>"   , "Go back", "Go forward", "close me"};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply

```
String[] options = new String[] {"Go ahead", "Go back", "Go forward", "close me"};
int option =  JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Title", "Message", 
      JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
      null, options, options[0]);

if (option != JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
  System.out.println(options[option]);
} else {
  System.out.println("No option selected".);
}
```

Note that use of an enum for the options will more easily allow use of the state or command design pattern.  For example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class OptionPaneEgWithEnums {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Title", "Message",
            JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null,
            State.values(), State.values()[0]);
      if (option == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
         // user closed the JOptionPane without selecting
      } else {
         State state = State.values()[option];
         doAction(state);
         // code to do something based selected state
      }
   }

   private static void doAction(State state) {
      System.out.println("The user has selected to " + state);
   }
}

enum State {
   AHEAD("Go Ahead"), BACK("Go Back"), FORWARD("Go Forward"), CLOSE("Close Me");
   private State(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

   private String text;

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

Comment: Although @Sambhav in his example gave a printing example, I won't be printing out the option name. I need each of them to do a different command. I think having a if statement for each would be better.

Comment: @Seeker: use of an enum for the options will more easily allow use of the State or Command design pattern.

Comment: would it be possible to use switch cases instead of if statements?

Comment: I have given a try but it is not working. two second going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Just see option is of int type. Hence JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Title", "Message", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,null, options, options[0]) is returning an integer value. 

You may use it as:

     if (option == 0) {
                  System.out.println("Go Ahead");
              } else if ( option == 1) {
                  System.out.println("Go back");
              } else if (option == 2 ) {
                  System.out.println("Go forward");
              } else if (option == 3) {
                  System.out.println("close me");
              }
```

Comment: would it be possible, say for example if the text on one of the button is long e.g. "Open window 2 and close window 1" then would it it possible to split them to two lines e.g. open window 2 on the first line and close window 1 on the second line.

Comment: why not simply `options[option]`?